# Is there an adverb for smell?

Tags: adverbs

Earlier in the day, a coworker of mine referred to a spreadsheet as "visually arresting," implying that it was pleasing to the eye. Later today on an elevator ride, we all experienced the breath of a third coworker in close proximity. I desperately wanted to say afterward to him that the smell was "_____ly arresting" but I could not find the adverb for it!

My first thought is olfactorily but I find this to be clunky. Is there a word that would have helped me make this joke?

Comment: [Olfactorily](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/olfactorily)

Comment: I would try *bacteriologically* arresting, and maybe plug my nose at the same time.

Comment: I would say nothing. He might thump you.

Comment: I would have waited until the olfactory offender was out of earshot.

Comment: I initially misread your "earshot" comment as meaning "waiting until they were too far away to smell". Is there are word similar to "earshot" for this concept?

Comment: I keep wanting to suggest _nosily arresting_…

Comment: Hmm, you found the smell *arresting* (no descriptor needed) and wanted to continue the experience by engaging in conversation?

Answer (score 15):

***Olfactorily***, is the word.   -   *To the sense of smell; as regards smell* (OED).  But if it sounds too highbrow/clunky, then, for the sample sentence you give, *malodorously* arresting.

> 1858   G. A. Sala Journey due North 324   The kitchen's contiguity to me is not near enough to be ***olfactorily*** disagreeable.
>
> 1888   Cent. Mag. 35 363   He was ***olfactorily*** impressed.
>
> 1944   R. W. Moncrieff Chem. Senses ix. 187   Structurally, the esters bear the same relation to the acids as the ethers do to the alcohols... ***Olfactorily***, however, there is a difference.
>
> 1993   S. Townsend Adrian Mole: Wilderness Yrs. 66   I found the fresh air ‘pine tree’ hanging from the roof of his taxi to be much more ***olfactorily*** offensive.

Comment: +1 Hard to insult someone when they don't know what you are saying!

Comment: Oh come on, @ab2!  I really think most people know what the word olfactory means and therefore would immediately know what olfactor-ily meant if they've never heard it before.  I'm one of those!

Comment: Being obscurely insulting is better than being overtly insulting.  My comment was a compliment.

Answer (score 9):

***nasally*** arresting

nasal, from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nasal):

> of or relating to the nose
>
> ................
>
> nasally, adverb

The virtue of this word is that you can say

> My, now that is nasally arresting!

in a neutral -- perhaps even admiring -- tone of voice and avoid being overtly insulting.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125190?redirectedFrom=nasally#eid):  offers support for this use of **nasally**:

> 2. By or through the nose; towards the nose; with regard to the nose.
>
> 1845   Amer. Rev. Sept. 286/1   Let not the worshippers of Fashion be
>   longer stigmatized as nose-led by a Parisian Dandy..as nasally guided
>   by the savor of ‘flesh-pots’.
>
> ..............
>
> 1911   Mind 20 295   Nasally, all stimulation tends to be localised on
>   the opposite side, though stimuli well forward may be placed on the
>   same side.
>
> '''''''''''''
>
> 2001   Phoenix New Times (Nexis) 29 Mar.   He wasn't even sure if Judi
>   had swallowed the drug, or had taken it nasally.

Comment: Haha!  Actually, that is pretty funny, too.  Still think *olfactorily* arresting is funnier though. ;)

Comment: Yes!  Imprecise, but funny for that.

Comment: *Now that is nasally arresting!* - #AccidentalPartridge

Comment: +1 for being immediately understandable in the context of a joke.

Answer (score 6):

***Olfactorily*** in my opinion is [one of] the *only* words that would work here.  (I disagree with Dan slightly in this regard so I won't delete my answer as a duplicate). It corresponds perfectly with visually -- and, the parallelism is necessary to make the joke funny.  It would have been hilarious IMO if you'd have said it.  I'm chuckling just thinking about it. ;)

> Olfactorily (adv.) To the sense of smell; as regards smell.

([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/258423?redirectedFrom=olfactorily#eid))

Dan beat me to the OED quotations for usage (see his answer).

**EDIT:**

Nasally arresting is pretty funny, too, but pungent and others like it are too specific.

Comment: Totally agree. Jinx!

Comment: Haha!  Dan is the man by 1 minute... but then you say that *malodoursly* arresting could work...I really think that the joke would be lost if any word *other than* olfactorily was used.  It's a parallelism thing IMO.

Comment: Yes.  I agree.  My 'cop out' is an attempt to square the fact that the OP is not content with *olfactorily*.

Answer (score 3):

I like this one in particular:

"Wow, how **noisomely** arresting!".

[Noisomely](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noisome)

> a :  offensive to the senses and especially to the sense of smell
> noisome garbage
>
> b :  highly obnoxious or objectionable noisome habits
>
> noisomely adverb
>
> noisomeness noun

**Source:** [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noisome)

Comment: It's such an interesting word imho. I've always thought so. It does not relate to *cacophony* or come from any *noise* word origin. Its comes from the root middle english word to annoy (noy). It's a great word for any offensive odorous usage.

Comment: @ab2 I agree, much better. I'll update the phrasing. I like it because otherwise it's a little bit of a double usage (noisomely already describes odor).

Answer (score 0):

How about "malodorous" for something negative or "fragrant" for something positive? "Malodorously arresting" or "fragrantly arresting" would be the result.

Comment: Doesn't correspond with visually and therefore the parallelism that would make the joke funny would be lost. (Same as for pungent.)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not a 100% transliteration of the joke, but if you're concerned about the clunkiness how about malodorous' less negative root: 'odorously'?   [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/odorously) at least, says it's a word and gives a delightful example:

> The kitchens, stables and outhouses were odorously barbaric in
>   squalor.

Answer (score 0):

I may have said stinkingly unpleasant or even stinkingly arresting. Olfactorily is too clunky. Since I like to get through life with the least number of problems I would have said nothing. We are told that Dr. Johnson insisted on differentiating between the verbs "smell" and "stink".

Answer (score 0):

How about, "odoriferously arresting".

Answer (score -1):

**Pungent** - having an intense flavor or odor ([MWO](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pungent))

On the dictionary page it confirms that **pungently** is a real word.

Comment: Doesn't correspond with visually and therefore the parallelism that would make the joke funny would be lost.